# GB18030 characters gets replaced with empty space for file name while downloading a file

Tags: java, spring, http, jsp, servlets

[image]

Hello Forum members,

I am not able to find out the reason for GB18030 characters gets replaced with empty spaces when I am downloading a file. Attached my code for your reference.

```
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String keyname = request.getParameter("keyname");
        String format = request.getParameter("format");

        // To be executed during check-out operation only.
        if (format != null && keyname != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream inStream = null;
            try {
                pgpPublicKeyInfoDb = new PGPPublicKeyInfoDb();
                inStream = pgpPublicKeyInfoDb.checkOutPGPPublicKey(keyname, format);
                response.setContentLength(inStream.size());
                if (format.equals("ASC")) {
                    response.setContentType("application/asc; charset=UTF-8");
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + keyname + ".asc");
                } else {
                    response.setContentType("application/pgp; charset=UTF-8");
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + keyname + ".pgp");
                }
                inStream.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

non-ASCII characters in filename parameters are invalid, and browsers vary in what they do with them.

If you need a reliable and portable solution, you need to use UTF-8 and the escaping defined in https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html.